# Zend search form

Tags: html, zend-framework, forms

I have created a form within the layout which is intended to be used across the site as a search box - The problem is that whenever the form is submitted the request string is appended to the existing URL

Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Regards,
Bert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is the "setAction" Method, because it is missing your baseUrl!.

If you want to submit your request with GET Method try this:

```
 $view = $this->getView();
 $baseUrl = $view->baseUrl();
 $this->setAction($baseUrl . '/categorey/listproducts');
```

If you want to submit your request with POST Method try this:

```
 $view = $this->getView();
 $baseUrl = $view->baseUrl();
 $this->setAction($baseUrl . '/categorey/listproducts');
 $this->setMethod('POST');
```

Altough you could override the "setAction" Method from Zend_Form and set baseUrl to your action by default.

Comment: I would advise going with GET for a search form as you are attempting to retrieve data, not submitting it.

Comment: Thanks ArneRie - Worked like a charm